# Can't run Homebrew anymore

Tags: macos, catalina, homebrew

I've been installing packages using Homebrew until now. I just found that I can't even run homebrew basic commands:

```
$ brew --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:13:in `<main>'
    3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:13:in `require_relative'
    2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext/object/blank (LoadError)

$ brew help
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:13:in `<main>'
    3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:13:in `require_relative'
    2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext/object/blank (LoadError)
```

Looks like the application got corrupted or something, but at this point I'm not sure how to proceed. I have macOS Catalina latest Version 10.15.6 and recently upgraded Xcode to Rel.12

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Xcode12 install Command Line Tools which have newer ruby framework and your Brew version is not compatible with this one.

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue. Will post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue started when I upgraded to Catalina. For some reason (or maybe it's normal) Xcode was not up to date. Found that when I was not even able to run python3. So I move ahead and installed Xcode 12 and homebrew later:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

It took a while but homebrew now is up and running:

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 2.5.2
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 0dad6; last commit 2020-09-27)
```